# Dropdownlist displaying two gridviews

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I currently have a drop down list that on selected index changed it displays data in a GridView based of the value of the drop down list. However, it is displaying the data in the existing GridView and then displaying another gridview next to the existing one with the exact information. I am just trying to display the data in the existing open.

C# Code:

```
     protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
     EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source= 
         (local)\;Initial Catalog=SmallBatch;Integrated Security=True;"))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format("SELECT Item.ItemID, Item.ItemDesc, Stock_Take_Item.BarQuantity, Stock_Take_Item.StorageQuantity FROM Item INNER JOIN Stock_Take_Item ON Item.ItemID = Stock_Take_Item.ItemID INNER JOIN Stock_Take ON Stock_Take_Item.StockTakeIDNew = Stock_Take.StockTakeIDNew where Stock_Take.Username = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'"), con);
            DataAdapter.Fill(table);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = table;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
}
```

Existing Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal">


            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item ID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridview-header">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="itemIDAdmin" Text='<%# Eval("ItemID")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Description" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridview-header">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="itemDescAdmin" Text='<%# Eval("ItemDesc")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bar Quantity" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridview-header">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="barQuantityAdmin" Text='<%# Eval("BarQuantity")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Storage Quantity" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridview-header">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="storageQuantityAdmin" Text='<%# Eval("StorageQuantity")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Is it because you don't have a closing tag for the gridview? Kind of seems impossible.

Comment: @wazz my mistake